# Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 20 seconds

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have an e2e protractor-jasmine test in my angular application. I've just run the exact same test several times in a row and it stops at exactly one step. giving the same error: 
'Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 20 seconds'

What I have tried:
1. I attempted to make this an async function: ... header', async () => { ...
2. I have tried await(ing) the element: await element(by.css("[ng-click='siteDocLibCtrl.managePermissionsDialog($event)']")).click();
3. I have tried to browser.sleep(3000)

Jasmine version:2.8.0
npm version:
  npm: '6.4.1',
  ares: '1.15.0',
  cldr: '33.1',
  http_parser: '2.8.0',
  icu: '62.1',
  modules: '64',
  napi: '3',
  nghttp2: '1.34.0',
  node: '10.15.0',
  openssl: '1.1.0j',
  tz: '2018e',
  unicode: '11.0',
  uv: '1.23.2',
  v8: '6.8.275.32-node.45',
  zlib: '1.2.11'

```
element.all(by.repeater("file in siteDocLibCtrl.files | filter:global.search | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort")).get(0).click(); //selects 1st element

element(by.css("[ng-click='siteDocLibCtrl.managePermissionsDialog($event)']")).click();
```

The output error i am getting is below:

```
Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 20 seconds
      (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)[0m
  Stack:
    ScriptTimeoutError: script timeout: result was not received in 20 seconds
      (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\Jagdeep\eclipse-workspace\ProtractorTutorial\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:546:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\Jagdeep\eclipse-workspace\ProtractorTutorial\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
        at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\Jagdeep\eclipse-workspace\ProtractorTutorial\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:441:30)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Any update regarding your error?

Answer (score 0):

Try add this line before the test:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

Comment: I tried 'browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;' too, it only worked for just one step and after that didnt work.

Comment: try to use `waitForAngularEnabled(false)` property instead.

Comment: If it doesn't help, I believe that you can solve your problem if you increase the default timeout, in addition to those properties.

Comment: I tried that too. Default timeout was 11seconds and i tried till a minute.